# Creating Managed Shared Memory using Boost Interprocess takes long time

Tags: c++, boost, boost-interprocess

I am using the Boost.Interprocess library on an Intel i7 processor with Windows Embedded 7 64bit operating system. I have successfully created 2 managed shared memories about 400 Megabytes size, from 2 different processes. When I try to create a 1 Gigabyte managed shared memory from a third process, it takes more than 5 minutes. There is plenty of free space in the drive.
The process gets stuck on function:

```
new managed_shared_memory(open_or_create, name, 1 Gigabyte);
```

Why is so slow? If I run this process alone, it takes less than 1 second.

Comment: And what is your question? An explanation why it is slow or are you looking for an alternative solution?

Comment: or why the process is stuck on the function 'managed_shared_memory'?

Answer (score 0):

> When I try to create a 1 Gigabyte managed shared memory from a third process,

Is it using another name? If not, it could be that another process holds a lock. If the other process crashed it might even have abandoned the lock in the held state. See also eg. [Boost interprocess mutexes and checking for abandonment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15772768/boost-interprocess-mutexes-and-checking-for-abandonment/15773373#15773373)

> it takes more than 5 minutes. There is plenty of free space in the drive. The process gets stuck on function: `managed_shared_memory::managed_shared_memory`

Shared memory is *memory*, not a file. If your system has too little memory to back the virtual realm, you will see a lot of swapping (is the disk very active during the wait? Then this is likely your problem).

If you wanted memory mapped files, use `managed_mapped_file`. No other changes required.