# Boost interprocess process crash when Memory allocation will lead to dead lock

Tags: boost, crash, mutex, interprocess

Code at http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_65_1/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/rbtree_best_fit.hpp (github: [#L664](https://github.com/boostorg/interprocess/blob/develop/include/boost/interprocess/mem_algo/rbtree_best_fit.hpp#L664)):

[image]

if process crash between lock and allocate, the mutex did not release
next time allocate will be stuck.
How can I deal with it??  use thread Non Thread-Safe allocator???

Comment: image contains code

Comment: First of all, never include code in screen shots. There's no reason to be so lazy and make it hard for people to read your question. Secondly, this is a duplicate. I'll close it as such in a minute

Comment: Also related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1179685/how-do-i-take-ownership-of-an-abandoned-boostinterprocessinterprocess-mutex/1179766#1179766